# Can one source predefined AWS bucket policies like Lego blocks?

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

Suppose that we have a requirement that all bucket policies should reject storage requests that don't include encryption information. A clean way would be to define this once as a template of sorts, then import that template into specific bucket policies when needed.

I cant seem to find anything that can do this, both in the AWS access policy language and in Terraform. I would like to do this in Terraform if possible, but any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: that's a great question/feature request(s). For bucket policies, AFAIK, you can't glue them together. With Terraform, I can see how you can pass in a chunk of a policy as a var into a template and construct a whole policy, but it would be messy!

Comment: @KJH, I ended up writing a tool using python and Jinja templates to generate terraform configs to make this work in a sufficiently clean manner.